# How to Bind and Customize ComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a **DataGrid** with multiple columns, the first is the type **ComboBoxColumn** and in it, the status of the record is displayed: active, canceled.

*If the registration status is active, it should be displayed in the combo "Active" with green letters; if the status is canceled, it should be displayed in the combo "Cancelled" with red letters.*

Something like that:

[image]

Each record must have the same combo but in a different state according to the database.
and every time the selection changes, the record is activated or deactivated in the DataGrid.

This is my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgPersons" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="All" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=lstPersons}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Status"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Carrer" Binding="{Binding Carrer}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is my class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Carrer { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to achieve what I explained in the description?